Get all items of a HTML element
Below is the output of alert( rd.innerHTML );:
 <ruby><rb>「わたし</rb><rt><br>watashi</rt></ruby><ruby><rb>は</rb><rt><br>wa</rt></ruby>」&lt;Name des Sprechers&gt;<br><ruby><rb>です</rb><rt><br>desu</rt></ruby>。

I like to iterate over all those nodes. I tried (among others):
var items = rd.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    alert( item.innerHTML);
}

But for the loop above I will get

<rb>「わたし</rb><rt><br>watashi</rt>
「わたし
\n watashi
 
<rb>は</rb><rt><br>wa</rt>
は
\n wa
 
 
<rb>です</rb><rt><br>desu</rt>
です
\n desu
 

How can I loop this HTML and also get the node 」&lt;Name des Sprechers&gt;<br>
Ideally I would like to have all rb elements and the text node in this order:

<rb>「わたし</rb><rt><br>watashi</rt>
<rb>は</rb><rt><br>wa</rt>
」&lt;Name des Sprechers&gt;<br>
<rb>です</rb><rt><br>desu</rt>

Background
I need this to convert single-sided furigana produced by Anki to double-sided furigana in case there is a <br> node within the furigana - as explained here.
The rd.innerHTML is the furigana produced by Anki. As @Pointy wrote, it...

...is not a single fragment; there are top-level elements (relative to the fragment) but no single enclosing tag.

Here is a card template including my setupCard() function after fixing it using @it-goldman 's solution:
<div class="jp" id="fldReading"> {{furigana:Reading}} </div><br>

<hr id=answer>

{{Meaning}}

<script language="javascript">

var rd = document.getElementById('fldReading');

/*
 * Use nested markup for double-sided ruby positioning
 * https://w3c.github.io/i18n-drafts/articles/ruby/styling.en#double_position
 */
function setupCard() {
    var newDiv;
    var parentRuby;
    var rubyDiv;

    /* Create a new div to hold the transformed structure */
    newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    /* Create a new div to hold the next ruby */
    rubyDiv = document.createElement('div');
    rubyDiv.className = 'jp';
    //alert( rd.innerText );
    //alert( rd.innerHTML );

    /* Iterate through all nodes to transform the structure */
    for (var child = rd.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        //alert( child.innerHTML + '<br>' + child.innerText  + '<br>' + child.textContent);
        if (child.nodeType != 3) {
            //alert( child.textContent );
            /* Add parent ruby element for nested markup */
            rubyDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('ruby'));
            parentRuby = rubyDiv.children[0];
            if(child.tagName === "RUBY") {
                /* get rb element */
                var rb = child.querySelector('rb');

                if(rb) {
                    //alert( rb.innerHTML );
                    /* Select the rt elements */
                    var rtElements = child.querySelectorAll('rt');
                    /* Create a new ruby element for the rb text */
                    var newRuby = document.createElement('ruby');
                    newRuby.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rb.textContent));
                    /* Append the new ruby to the parent ruby */
                    parentRuby.appendChild(newRuby);

                    /* Append rt elements to the new ruby */
                    rtElements.forEach((rt) => {
                        //alert( rt.innerHTML );
                        /* Split rt text at <br> */
                        var textWithLineBreaks = rt.innerHTML.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gi, '\n');
                        var arr = textWithLineBreaks.split('\n');
                        /* Create new rt element for hiragana furigana */
                        var newRt = document.createElement('rt');
                        newRt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[0]));
                        /* Append the new furigana to the new ruby */
                        newRuby.appendChild(newRt);

                        /* Is there is a second furigana (after <br>)? */
                        if (arr[1]) {
                            /* Create a new rt for the romaji furigana */
                            var newRt = document.createElement('rt');
                            newRt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[1]));
                            /* Append this directly to the parent ruby */
                            /* (for nested markup) */
                            parentRuby.appendChild(newRt);
                            /* Append a rb element (for nested markup) */
                            parentRuby.appendChild(document.createElement('rb'));
                        }
                    });
                    /* append the ruby structure */
                    newDiv.appendChild(rubyDiv);
                }
            }
            if(child.tagName === "BR") {
                    rubyDiv = document.createElement('div');
                    rubyDiv.className = 'jp';
                    /* Add parent ruby element for nested markup */
                    rubyDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('ruby'));
                    parentRuby = rubyDiv.children[0];
            }
        } else {
            //alert( child.textContent );
            /* append the text node */
            rubyDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(child.textContent));
            newDiv.appendChild(rubyDiv);
        }
    };

    /* Replace jp div content by the transformed HTML */
    rd.innerHTML = newDiv.innerHTML;
    //alert( newDiv.innerHTML );
}

setupCard();

</script>


Seems like that text needs to be directly in a tag. Can you modify rd.innerHTML?

I don't see how .innerHTML has anything to do with what you are trying to achieve (which is, admittedly, not very clear).  If you want to get an element, then in your loop item will be the element. The thing you say is an "item" is not an item in the DOM; it's one or more text nodes and a <br> node.

@Pointy I edited my questions.

The HTML fragment you posted is not a single fragment; there are top-level elements (relative to the fragment) but no single enclosing tag. The content you want is not in any tag at all; it will exist as a list of one or more text nodes and that <br> node as children of whatever parent element contains all of the HTML you posted.

Where did Sprechers disappear in your output? Well you need to traverse the nodes rather than the elements. I'm re-using a function to extract text nodes from a node / element.


var html = `<ruby><rb>「わたし</rb><rt><br>watashi</rt></ruby><ruby><rb>は</rb><rt><br>wa</rt></ruby>」&lt;Name des Sprechers&gt;<br><ruby><rb>です</rb><rt><br>desu</rt></ruby>`

var rd = document.createElement("div");
rd.innerHTML = html;


function textUnder(node) {
  var all = [];
  for (node = node.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
      console.log("text node of " + node.parentElement.tagName + ": " +  node.textContent)
      all.push(node.textContent);
    } else {
      all = all.concat(textUnder(node));
    }
  }
  return all;
}

var texts = textUnder(rd)
console.log(texts)
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}




Thank you. Your loop for (node = node.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) and the check for node type if (node.nodeType == 3) helped me to solve my issue. The first loop I used, before trying the one in my question was for (var child = rd.firstElementChild; child; child = child.nextElementSibling). But as you said: "you need to traverse the nodes rather than the elements

I think this is kind of tricky question.
If my guess is rigth, you're trying to separate japanese texts from ocidental ones...
Try the snippet below. All names are self explanatories.


const myContainer = document.getElementById('myContent');

console.log('Language separation:', separateLanguages(myContainer));

function separateLanguages ( myContent )
{
  const myChildren = myContent.childNodes;
  const myTexts = [];
  
  for ( const myNode of myChildren )
  {
    // Separates ocidental texts.
    if ( myNode.nodeName == '#text' )
    {
      // Edit: added the replaceEntities function.
      myTexts.push(replaceEntities(myNode.wholeText));
    }
    
    // Separates oriental texts.
    else if ( myNode.nodeName == 'RUBY' )
    {
      myTexts.push(myNode.innerHTML);
      
      // If you wish to include the <ruby> tag, then use the line below
      // instead of the line above.
      
      // myTexts.push(myNode);
    }
    
    // Separates any other content.
    else
    {
      // Keep the line breaks in previous index.
      if ( myNode.nodeName == 'BR' )
      {
        myTexts[myTexts.length -1] = myTexts.at(-1) + myNode.outerHTML;
      }
      
      else
      {
        myTexts.push(myNode.outerHTML);
      }
    }
  }
  
  return myTexts;
}

// Replaces special html characters from an unparsed text to html entities.
function replaceEntities ( text )
{
  // Add as many entities as you wish to convert.
  const entityMap =
  {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
  }
  
  for ( const placeHolder in entityMap )
  {
    text = text.replaceAll(placeHolder, entityMap[placeHolder]);
  }
  
  return text;
}
<div id="myContent"><ruby><rb>「わたし</rb><rt><br>watashi</rt></ruby><ruby><rb>は</rb><rt><br>wa</rt></ruby>」&lt;Name des Sprechers&gt;<br><ruby><rb>です</rb><rt><br>desu</rt></ruby>。</div>



NOTE: The function separateLanguages will only iterate over the root element, not its children.

@Yogi, I fixed this issue adding the replaceEntities function.

Text nodes can be iterated over with regular nodes using document.createTreeWalker().
In the example below, only text nodes are selected. If you need to get text nodes mixed with ordinary elements and, for example, comments in the code, then the filters are added by a mathematical operation bitwise or |:
NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT | NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT | NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT

A full list of search options is available on the MDN page.


 let text = [], 
        treewalker = document.createTreeWalker(
            document.body, 
            NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
            null, 
            false);
    
    while(treewalker.nextNode()) {   
        if (treewalker.currentNode.nodeValue.charAt(0) !== '\n') {
            text.push(treewalker.currentNode);
        }     
    };
    
    console.log(text.map( node => node.data ));    
    console.log('Total: ' + text.length);
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Ui lab training</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <div class="img"></div>
            <h1>EPAM SUSTEMS</h1>
            <p>Ui lab training</p>
        </div>
       <menu class="menu">
            <a href="#">About UI lab</a>
            <a href="#">Home Tasks</a>
            <a href="#">Tests & Exems</a>
        </menu>
    </header>
    <main>
    <nav class="nav-left">
        <ul class="cotegory">
            <li><a href="#">Vertical navigation sample</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vertical navigation sample</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vertical navigation sample</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vertical navigation sample</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vertical navigation sample</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vertical navigation sample</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <article>
        <h2>Level 2 Heading</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, laboriosam 
            fuga. Voluptatibus earum neque, nihil, ea, sapiente tempora modi facere 
            dolorum optio veniam error deleniti laudantium recusandae. Fuga, molestiae, 
            architecto iste voluptate aliquid eligendi accusamus corrupti placeat 
            inventore obcaecati illum in fugiat provident deserunt, modi possimus iure? 
            Repellendus quisquam nemo officia veniam natus vel praesentium quibusdam 
            non consectetur corporis rerum ullam facilis animi fugit inventore id optio 
            luta magnam, nam perferendis quas eaque iusto saepe. Ducimus, eligendi 
            labore? Totam porro tenetur qui vero omnis aspernatur eum molestias deleniti 
            harum aliquid veniam incidunt voluptatum saepe suscipit, animi impedit, 
            laboriosam magnam nihil?
        </p>
        <h2>Level 3 Heading</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>BasicListSample</li>
            <li>BasicListSample</li>
            <li>BasicListSample</li>
            <li>BasicListSample</li>
            <li>BasicListSample</li>
            <li>BasicListSample</li>
            <li>BasicListSample</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </article>
    </main>
</body>
<footer>
    
</footer>
</html>



